# How to use Required Attribute along with Validation in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a field called Passenger Name which is a mandatory field (need to show *). And this field is shown when a checkbox is checked. I need to validate the field if the passenger is empty. We are using MVC in the project.

I tried with the below code :

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Passenger Name mandatory if specifying Enhanced Data")]
public string PassengerName { get; set; }
```

This is getting fired even if the checkbox is not checked. I need to validate this only when checkbox is checked..

Kindly help!

Comment: you need to use validation summary on client side to show this error message.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use custom validation attribute for this.

Here is the sample code

public class RequiredIfAttribute : RequiredAttribute
        {
            private String PropertyName { get; set; }
            private Object DesiredValue { get; set; }

```
        public RequiredIfAttribute(String propertyName, Object desiredvalue)
        {
            PropertyName = propertyName;
            DesiredValue = desiredvalue;
        }

        protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext context)
        {
            Object instance = context.ObjectInstance;
            Type type = instance.GetType();
            Object proprtyvalue = type.GetProperty(PropertyName).GetValue(instance, null);
            if (proprtyvalue.ToString() == DesiredValue.ToString())
            {
                 ValidationResult result = base.IsValid(value, context);
                return result;
            }
            return ValidationResult.Success;
        }
    }
```

Here PropertyName is the property on which you want to make your condition DesiredValue is the particular value of the PropertyName (property) for which your other property has to be validated for required

Say you have the following

```
public enum UserType
{
 Admin,
 Regular
}

public class User
{
   public UserType UserType{get;set;}
   [RequiredIf("UserType",UserType.Admin,ErrorMessageResourceName="PasswordRequired", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(ResourceString))
   public string Password
   {
   get;
   set;
   }
}
```

At last but not the least , register adapter for your attribute so that it can do client side validation (I put it in global.asax, Application_Start)

```
DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.RegisterAdapter(typeof(RequiredIfAttribute),typeof(RequiredAttributeAdapter));
```